# Duplicate DataFrame with new columns with different values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

d = {'account_id': [1, 2], 'type': ['a', 'b']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

|  | account_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 2 | b |

I want to add two columns `include_images` and `data_since` which should contain one time `True` and a date for every row of the original DataFrame and one time `False` and `NaN` for every row of the original DataFrame.

Is there a more efficient way of writing this then like so:

```
df_a = df.copy()
df_a['include_images'] = True
df_a['data_since'] = datetime(2018, 1, 1)

df_b = df.copy()
df_b['include_images'] = False
df_b['data_since'] = np.nan

df = pd.concat([df_a, df_b], ignore_index=True)
```

|  | account_id | type | include_images | data_since |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a | True | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | b | True | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | a | False | NaT |
| 3 | 2 | b | False | NaT |

Comment: what do you mean by more efficient here? is it to have a more parametric way to do it because your end goal is to duplicates df many times with a lot of different values in the two extra columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `assign` which creates a copy on-the-fly:

```
const_date = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01')

out = pd.concat([df.assign(include_img=True, data_since=const_date),
                 df.assign(include_img=False, data_since=pd.NaT)],
                ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
   account_id type  include_img data_since
0           1    a         True 2018-01-01
1           2    b         True 2018-01-01
2           1    a        False        NaT
3           2    b        False        NaT
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df], ignore_index=True)
df['include_images'] = False
df['data_since'] = np.nan
df.loc[range(len(df) // 2), ('include_images', 'data_since')] = (True, datetime(2018, 1, 1))
```